# Moving anchor point more precise

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have logged in with another Adobe account on Ai and now when I try to move one single anchor point, I can't move it very precise, moving steps are too big/large. Is this a setting I have to adjust?

Comment: Do you have a rgb image profile. if so you may have pixel snapping on. just disable it (general advice would be to never enable it for any reason)

Comment: *How* are you moving them.... that will make a difference in what is adjusted... snap to grid.. keyboard increments...

Answer (score 1):

Go to Illustrator > Preferences > General > Keyboard Increment
and change the value there. You can use mm or inch or points or any of the measurement units that Illustrator recognizes.

This is assuming you are trying to move anchors/ objects by selecting them and using the arrow keys on the keyboard.

You can also use shift + arrow key to move 10 times whatever keyboard Increment you have set in the preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Select the anchor with the direct selection tool, open Transform > Move dialog and type the exact horizontal and vertical displacements.

Lock in the Layers pane all wrong items which are close the anchor you want to move. Otherwise it's too easy to select and move a wrong item.

Or if there's already another anchor waiting in the destination, simply move the anchor with the direct selection tool. It snaps if you have Smart Guides and Snap to Point checked.

Anything which tries to crunch the image pixel perfect or to snap to grid causes problems if the destination is differently aligned.